# Selection of data in a single dimension (which can vary) in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, selection

Say I have a multi-dimensional array of shape (80,80,17,5,27), where 27 (the slice axis) can be in the third, fourth, or fifth dimension.

I would like to select a subset of data within the slice axis; as an example:

```
slice_axis = N.shape(data).index(27) # slice_axis=4 for data listed above
data_new = data[:,:,:,:,0:tot_slices/2] # where this selection location depends on the slice axis
```

Alternatively, if the data shape looks like this: (80,80,27,17,5):
Then slice_axis=2 and `data_new = data[:,:,0:tot_slices/2,:,:]`

Is there a quick way to do this, preferably without having to transpose the data?

Comment: Wait.. What? What do you mean by, "# where this selection location depends on the slice index." What selection location? What is an example of data_new you would like to achieve?

Comment: I went to select a portion of the data in the fifth dimension of the data array in my example; the fifth dimension corresponding to the slice index of interest (as from the line above).

Comment: It is still not clear to me. You might want to click edit, and edit your question. It would really help if you gave some example. Can you include a example of what your code and would like to do (fill in the line you dont know with a comment or psedo-code)?

Comment: Is the case that you want data[:,:,:,:,0:tot_slices/2] if the fifth dimension is 27 long, or data[:,:,:,0:tot_slices/2,:] if the fourth dimension is 27 long, etc.?

Comment: Yes, mdurant, that is exactly what I am asking. I re-edited the question to make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should work:

```
slice_idx = N.shape(data).index(27)
slices = [ slice( 0, None, None),]*4
slices.insert( slice_idx, slice( 0, tot_slices/2, None))
data_new = data.__getitem__(slices)
```

Comment: Yes, this does what I want (although I don't fully understand it yet). I will also post the solution that I came up with below.

Comment: Essentially, the normal square-bracket notation maps to `__getitem__`, with each part becoming a `slice` object. This is doing that process manually.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came up with before mdurant answered it is as follows:

```
selected_axis = N.shape(data).index(27) 

# delete 1 dynamic to create an even split of the data (because 27 is an odd number)
data = N.delete(data,N.ceil(27/2), axis=selected_axis) 
        
(data_base,data_activation) = N.split(data,2,axis=selected_axis)
```